# Proving $\text{erf}(\sqrt{t})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{e^{-\tau}}{\sqrt{\tau}} \;d\tau$

Tags: error-function

I started by using the error function:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{erf}(y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{y} e^{-u^{2}} du,
\end{align}
$$

where I let $\tau=u^{2}$ then $d\tau=2u\;du$, $du=\frac{d\tau}{2u}=\frac{d\tau}{2\sqrt{\tau}}$. Then substituting and letting $y=\sqrt{t}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{erf}(\sqrt{t})=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}} e^{-\tau} \frac{d\tau}{2\sqrt{\tau}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}} \frac{e^{-\tau}}{\tau} \;d\tau,
\end{align}
$$

the only problem is with $\sqrt{t}$ in the upper limit when it should be $t$, any idea how can I arrive to this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $\tau=u^{2}$ maps $[0, y]$ onto $[0, y^2]$, so the boundaries of the integral must be substituted as well:
$$
\operatorname{erf}(y)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{y} e^{-u^{2}} du
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{y^2} \frac{e^{-\tau}}{\sqrt \tau} d\tau
$$
Now set $y=\sqrt t$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Ah! I don't know how I completely missed that. Thank you so much!